# A loop that prints even numbers?

Tags: java

I was supposed to write a code that asks for a name, asks for a number between 1 and 10, and then prints the numbers from 1 to the number the user entered except every third number should be the user's name that was entered at the beginning of the program. My code fulfills that purpose. The next step is to use a loop that prints all the even numbers from 2 to the user's number. I'm not sure how to include this in my code or even what kind of loop I should use. Can someone explain how to include this correctly? Here is the code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        number = scan.nextInt();

        //asks for a number between one and ten until I get number within that range,
        while (number < 1 || number > 10) {
            System.out.print("No, between 1 and 10: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print(name + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need a loop that starts at 2 and prints every second number. What part of that are you having trouble with? It's basically just putting the values in and adding a print.

Comment: Use one more loop similar to the one you have, except if not `i % 2 == 0` print nothing at all, that is, leave out the `else` part of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code for your reference:

```
 public class NewClass1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       int number;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
       String name = scan.nextLine();

       System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
       number = scan.nextInt();

    //asks for a number between one and ten until I get number within that range,
      while (number < 1 || number > 10) {
          System.out.print("No, between 1 and 10: ");
          number = scan.nextInt();
      }

     for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
         if (i % 3 == 0) {
             System.out.print(name + " ");
         }else {
             System.out.print(i + " ");
         }
     }
     System.out.println();
     for(int i =2; i<=number; i+=2)
         System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Running a loop that prints on every even number is no different then running a loop that prints on every third number. Simply use `% 2` instead of `% 3`:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % 2 = 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Which can be re-written without using `%` at all:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= number; i += 2) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[]p){
   int limit=20;
   for(int i=2; i<=limit; i+=2)
   {
      System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example where you can print all the even numbers up to 100.

```
int number = 0;
while (number <= 100) {
  number += 1;

  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution with java 8 stream api and range function:

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    IntStream stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number);
    stream.filter( i -> i % 2 ==0).forEach( i -> System.out.format("%d\t",i));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % 2 = 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

The above is the code.

Comment: Try to add some explanation about your code to enrich your answer.